# How to handle a list of byte array in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currently designing a web api to return a list of documents.

```
public class Document : IIdentifier<int> {

    public Document() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string AddDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

It can be a list of 1000 documents. Some of the files are about 36 MB each.

**Performance wise, is it a good idea to return a list of byte[] of this size?**

I was thinking converting the **byte[] to Base64String**

```
    public static string ReadFile(string path) {      
        var doc = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(doc);
    }
```

But the size is still very large.

Comment: What about using Pagination?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using pagination or returning a List of URL's to every file. I have never tried it, but I'm positive that returning GB's of data from a controller is not a good idea. Your conversion to Base64String will do nothing for that.

Comment: I agree with @Kenneth. I would save the files on the server and then send back the URLs to retrieve the files.

Comment: I would add a third nominate to the idea of providing a list of URLs if possible. 1000 file x 36MB/file = 36000 MB or ~ 36 GB in one web request. Even if it is possible, the response would extremely slow.